# Print statement inside method

Tags: python-2.7, wing-ide

So I am trying to write make a function that will initialize two points and output previously made methods.

Partial code below:

```
    class Point(Geometry):
next_id = 0
def __init__(self,x,y,):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.id = Point.next_id
    Point.next_id += 1  
def __str__(self):
    return "(%0.2f, %0.2f)" % (self.x, self.y)

def quadrat(self):
        if (self.x > 0 and self.y > 0):
            return "Quad I"
        elif (self.x < 0 and self.y > 0):
            return "Quad II"
        elif (self.x < 0 and self.y < 0):
            return "Quad III"
        elif (self.x > 0 and self.y < 0):
            return "Quad IV"
        elif (self.x == 0 and self.y == 0):
            return "Origin"        
        elif (self.x == 0):
            return "Y-axis"
        elif (self.y == 0):
            return "X-axis"

def distance(p0, p1):
    dist = math.sqrt((p0.x - p1.x)**2 + (p0.y - p1.y)**2)
    return dist

def equality():
        if (self.x == self.y):
            print "True"
        else:
            print "False"  

def identify():
        if(p0.id == p1.id):
            print "True"
        else:
            print "False"
def pointTest():
    global P1,P2
    P1 = Point(-3,-3)
    P2 = Point(0,0)
    print "P1) ID =", P1.id,", Coordinates=", P1,", Location=",P1.quadrat()
    print "P2) ID =", P2.id,", Coordinates=", P2,", Location=",P2.quadrat()
    print "Distance between",P1,"and",P2,"is %0.2f" % (P1.distance(P2))
    print "P1==P2?",P1==P2
    print "P1 same as P2?",P1.id==P2.id    

P1 = None    
P2 = None    
print pointTest()
```

When my points are defined outside the method and when the `print` statements are outside the method, my output comes out perfectly.

But I need the points to be initialized in the method and my `print` statement to be within the method as well.

When I call it, I get the error that `pointTest` is not defined.

My output needs to look like this:

```
<<<< print pointTest
```

Which will give me the answers to my print statements.

Comment: `print` is not a statement in Python 3, but a function. I believe you meant to tag Python 2 instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to initialize your variables in a different method from `__init__`, then you must either pass them to the initialization method and access their attributes directly:

```
def pointTest(p1, p2):
    p1.x = -3
    p1.y = -3 
    p2.x = 0
    p2.y = 0

p1 = Point()
p2 = Point()

pointTest(p1, p2)
```

or declare them as global variables, which is generally a bad idea but can be a quick workaround:

```
def pointTest():
    global p1, p2
    p1 = Point(-3, -3)
    p2 = Point(0, 0)

p1 = None
p2 = None

pointTest()
```

In both cases, you can add the call to `print` inside of the `pointTest` method.

Note that in the second case, you don't need to declare `p1` and `p2` as `None`, but it's better to make every variable explicit. You don't want your methods to make global variables pop out, that you weren't aware of.

---

It seems that in addition, your `pointTest` method appears as undefined.

Regarding your original indentation, it seems that your `pointTest` method is indeed inside of a code block.

Therefore, the `pointTest` method is probably declared only in a deeper scope than where you call it, and thus, is not defined. Either put it outside of that block, or put all your consequent `print`s in that block.

Comment: for the first example i get the error "TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)"

Comment: @A_Worthy Of course, you need to have a constructor that takes zero arguments (so one, because of `self`). You can initialize them with `Point(0,0)` instead. For the second case, read what I added after the separator.